# Recursively find all entity's n-generation children in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

There's an entity called category, in user's terms it may be viewed as a directory, this directory may contains an arbitrary number of subdirs that, in turn, may have its own subdirs and so on and so forth.
So it's just a simple tree of dirs. What I need is, given a dirs (category's) id , to find all its children, that's to say all those n-th level deep  subcategories contained in this given category.

```
id|name                 |parentCategoryId|userId|
--|---------------------|----------------|------|
85|ToDo                 |                |     7|
95|plans for the weekend|              85|     7|
96|things to buy        |              95|     7|
```

Given id = 85, the result would be 95 and 96.

I tried doing it with a recursive approach but it didn't work.

EDIT:

```
with recursive subcategories as (
    select id, "name", "parentCategoryId"
    from category c2 
    where id = 85
    union
        select c3.id, c3."name", c3."parentCategoryId"
        from category c3
        inner join subcategories subs on subs."id" = subs."parentCategoryId"
) select * from subcategories
```

I tried this, but I don't seem to understand how exactly this function works...now it just returns this:

```
id|name|parentCategoryId|
--|----|----------------|
85|ToDo|                |
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what error/unexpected result you obtained. Also please use CTE (with clause) rather than plaintext tables to specify your input data. Or prepare dbfiddle. It helps to concentrate on answer instead of text formatting.

Comment: Do you want to go to n-levels deep and stop or find all descendants? What didn't work about the recursive approach?

Comment: @TomášZáluský Please, have a look at the update.

Comment: @JSpratt I need to find all children and children of those children and so on. So I think yes, I need all the descendants.

Comment: I've posted an answer just as you were updating the question but from inspection it looks like you're joining the tables backwards. In the `UNION` query, you should be selecting `FROM subcategories` and joining `categories`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just fix where condition and add level of nesting.

```
with recursive subcategories as (
    select id, "name", "parentCategoryId", 0 as level
    from category c2 
    where id = 85
    union
        select c3.id, c3."name", c3."parentCategoryId", subs.level + 1
        from category c3
        inner join subcategories subs on subs."id" = c3."parentCategoryId"
        where subs.level < YOUR_LIMIT
) select * from subcategories
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always done this type of query with a `RECURSIVE CTE`. Here is an example using a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_findAllDescendants(startid INTEGER)
RETURNS SETOF test
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
    (
        SELECT *
          FROM test t
         WHERE t.id = startid
         UNION
        SELECT descendant.*
          FROM cte parent
          JOIN test descendant ON (parent.id = descendant.parentCategoryID)
    ) SELECT * FROM cte; -- If you don't want the root record add WHERE id <> startid to this query
END;
$$  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9qza3JphpFXJDkaf8ycZKD/0) is a DBFiddle showing it in action.

The idea here is to start building a CTE (common table expression) with one record...the startid record and then build the rest of the CTE from there recursively.

1. Select starting point. id = 85
2. Find records in the real table (by joining against the CTE) that have the starting point ID as its parentID.
3. Find records in the real table that have the ID from step 2 as its parentID.
4. Repeat until a record's parentID cannot be found.

Comment: You don't actually need PL/pgSQL for that: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9qza3JphpFXJDkaf8ycZKD/0

Comment: Seriously, I don't know what answer to chose. They are both great and helpful.